# Convert string into single array, PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, laravel

I am working in a Laravel project. I want to convert a string into single array in efficient way.

String is 
 `$string = txn_status=0|txn_msg=success|txn_err_msg=NA|clnt_txn_ref=969239|tpsl_bank_cd=470|tpsl_txn_id=192630337|txn_amt=1.00|clnt_rqst_meta={itc:NIC~TXN0001~122333~rt14154~8 mar 2014~Payment~forpayment}{custname:test}|tpsl_txn_time=26-12-2015 15:56:20|tpsl_rfnd_id=NA|bal_amt=NA|rqst_token=hdfs-df-jkfhskjfhsjkd|hash=jhdsfs54367jhf,`

And I want output look like below format. It is a json format:-

```
[ txn_status: "0",
  txn_msg : "success",
  txn_err_msg: "NA",
  .
  .
  .


  hash: "XYZ" ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) in conjunction with the [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) like this:

```
$string = "txn_status=0|txn_msg=success|txn_err_msg=NA|clnt_txn_ref=969239|tpsl_bank_cd=470|tpsl_txn_id=192630337|txn_amt=1.00|clnt_rqst_meta={itc:NIC~TXN0001~122333~rt14154~8 mar 2014~Payment~forpayment}{custname:test}|tpsl_txn_time=26-12-2015 15:56:20|tpsl_rfnd_id=NA|bal_amt=NA|rqst_token=hdfs-df-jkfhskjfhsjkd|hash=jhdsfs54367jhf";

preg_match_all("/([^|]+)=([^|]+)/", $string, $array);

$output = array_combine($array[1], $array[2]);

echo json_encode($output, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

http://ideone.com/eXf5K2

Or the [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) like this:

```
$array = preg_split("/[|=]/", $string);
$output = [];

for ($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++) {
    $output[$array[$i]] = $array[++$i];
}
```

http://ideone.com/Y5k5bV

Or a simplified version of @devpro's code:

```
$array = explode("|", $string);
$output = [];

foreach ($array as $v) {
    list($key, $value) = explode("=", $v);
    $output[$key] = $value;
}
```

http://ideone.com/svrj8S

Comment: Hey pespantelis, thanx for answering multi solutions. May i know the solution if i want to break {key1:value1} {key2:value2}....{keyN:valueN} in above array. For ex, this whole value- {itc:NIC~TXN0001~122333~rt14154~8 mar 2014~Payment~forpayment} {custname:test}

Answer (score 5):

You can split as like that try this:

```
$string = "txn_status=0|txn_msg=success|txn_err_msg=NA|clnt_txn_ref=969239|tpsl_bank_cd=470|tpsl_txn_id=192630337|txn_amt=1.00|clnt_rqst_meta={itc:NIC~TXN0001~122333~rt14154~8 mar 2014~Payment~forpayment}{custname:test}|tpsl_txn_time=26-12-2015 15:56:20|tpsl_rfnd_id=NA|bal_amt=NA|rqst_token=hdfs-df-jkfhskjfhsjkd|hash=jhdsfs54367jhf";
$firstArray = explode("|", $string);
foreach ($firstArray as $key => $value) {
    $newArr = explode("=", $value);
    $myRequiredArr[$newArr[0]] = $newArr[1];
}

echo "<pre>"; // just for formatting
print_r($myRequiredArr); // print your result
```

**Result is:**

```
Array
(
    [txn_status] => 0
    [txn_msg] => success
    [txn_err_msg] => NA
    [clnt_txn_ref] => 969239
    [tpsl_bank_cd] => 470
    [tpsl_txn_id] => 192630337
    [txn_amt] => 1.00
    [clnt_rqst_meta] => {itc:NIC~TXN0001~122333~rt14154~8 mar 2014~Payment~forpayment}{custname:test}
    [tpsl_txn_time] => 26-12-2015 15:56:20
    [tpsl_rfnd_id] => NA
    [bal_amt] => NA
    [rqst_token] => hdfs-df-jkfhskjfhsjkd
    [hash] => jhdsfs54367jhf
)
```

Comment: This won't give the OP the result they expect. It will give a list of values like "txn_status=0", while the OP wants txn_status to be the key and 0 to be the value.

Comment: Sorry, but it gives result like this ["txn_status=0", "txn_msg=success",....], but I don't want like this format.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the combination of php functions `explode` , `array_map` and `call_user_func_array` like as

```
$string = "txn_status=0|txn_msg=success|txn_err_msg=NA|clnt_txn_ref=969239|tpsl_bank_cd=470|tpsl_txn_id=192630337|txn_amt=1.00|clnt_rqst_meta={itc:NIC~TXN0001~122333~rt14154~8 mar 2014~Payment~forpayment}{custname:test}|tpsl_txn_time=26-12-2015 15:56:20|tpsl_rfnd_id=NA|bal_amt=NA|rqst_token=hdfs-df-jkfhskjfhsjkd|hash=jhdsfs54367jhf";
$arr = array();
array_map(function($v)use(&$arr){ $a = explode("=",$v); return $arr[$a[0]]  = $a[1];},explode('|',$string));
print_r($arr);
```

[**Working Demo**](https://3v4l.org/W0Vut)